# Upload file image in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, image, asp.net-core, file-upload, asp.net-core-3.0

After saving the file to Wwwroot I encountered 1 problem. But don't know the reason why.
[This is the error I received after the add successfully this image file to Wwwroot. It asks to close 1 app that I don't know.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWP52.png)

But when I open the folder images and double-click on that image or rebuild Project, it's back to normal
[Here's the photo in the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnPPY.png)

[And here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oS1CU.png)

My Code:

1. [Code Save Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oevFj.png)
2. [Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3onq.png)

Comment: You should really post your code. It sounds like aren't correctly closing the stream when uploading the file.

Comment: Ok. Have Update :)

Comment: @coderpro I agree, I think he should be closing the stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code I recently typed for the same situation. Edited, just for you :)

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) 
{
    await file.CopyToAsync(ms);

    using (var writer = System.IO.File.Open(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
    {
        writer.Write(ms.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Note that this code will also open the file if it already exists, or create if it doesn't.

Also, by utilizing `using`'s we are cleaning-up after ourselves, memory wise.

Comment: Well. I tried and it works pretty good. But there are one problem is that I can't upload file larger 384kb :)

Answer (score -1):

This is happening when attempting to check-in pending changes(Conflict) because your project is on TFS.

**you must Checked-In Image Folder or Exclude the Image From Project**

Comment: Is it because i'm using GIT??